# React-component loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a react-component:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useHttp } from '../../hooks/http.hooks';

function Main() {
    const {loading, error, request} = useHttp();
    const [news, setNews] = useState(0);

    const topNews = useCallback(async function() {
        const data = await request('http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/2');
        return data;
    }, []);

    console.log(topNews());

    return (
        <div>Hello world</div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

And a custom hook:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useHttp = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    async function request(url, { method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {} } = {}) {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, { method, body, headers });
            const data = await response.json();

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(data.msg || 'unhandled error');
            }

            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    return { loading, request, error }
}
```

Starting it throw error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

And so many Promises in console:

[image]

As I understood, when `loading` is changing `Main` is rendering, because I added a `useCallback()` but it's not working. How to get rid of looping right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your React Component, `request` should be called inside `useEffect` instead of `useCallback`. If you keep it that way, the loop looks like this :

1. Component render
2. `request` is called
3. `request` update component states
4. states change force render, so go back to bullet #2

You should change your code to something like this :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHttp } from '../../hooks/http.hooks';

function Main() {
    const {loading, error, request} = useHttp();
    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const data = await request('http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/2');
      setNews(data);
    }, [])

    console.log(news);

    return (
        <div>Hello world</div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

See [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more details and advanced usage.

Answer (score 1):

Move the async function call to `useEffect`, you currently call it on every render:

```
function Main() {
    const {loading, error, request} = useHttp();
    const [news, setNews] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
      async function topNews() {
        const data = await request('http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/2');
        return data;
    }
      setNews(topNews());
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(news,null,2)}</div>
    );
}
```